# When entering into an agreement, is a term stating "you agree not to take legal action against us for damages" enforcable?

Tags: contract-law, canada, waivers

I know in settlement agreements there are provisions that basically state:

> You will not bring further legal action against the company.

I guess this shows that a contract can prevent a party from taking legal action against someone or something. I saw a waiver when joining a club that

> You agree not to sue any employees or owners of the company for any injuries or
> damages.

Is it enforceable to preemptively agree not to sue when first entering into a relationship?

Comment: settlements are fundamentally different from contracts

Comment: @TigerGuy Settlement agreements *are* contracts.